# update changes in array from server swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I have a method which get the data from FireBase, save it locally and load it into a UITableView. It's working great.

Now, this observer (**rootGenerals.observe()**) is running live and updating each time the data changing on the server.

My problem is that I don't want to reload the whole table once I get a new data (as I do now), I just want to update the specific changed row in the table or to replace the row location (IndexPath) if the score has changed.

Any idea of how to do it? Just need some guidance for what is the best way of handling in the situation.

```
    rootGenerals.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if !snapshot.exists() { return }

        let general = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

        if let users : NSDictionary = general.object(forKey: "users") as? NSDictionary
        {
            if (self.usersFromDB?.count != 0) {
                //  Update table rows
                self.arrRecords = []
            }
            else {
                //  Create table from scratch
                self.usersFromDB = users

                for user : Any in users.allKeys {
                    let userDict : NSDictionary = users.object(forKey: user as! String) as! NSDictionary
                    let record : Record = Record()

                    record.displayName  = userDict.object(forKey: "name") as! String
                    record.time         = userDict.object(forKey: "time") as! Int
                    record.solvedLogos  = userDict.object(forKey: "logos_solved") as! Int
                    record.deviceId     = userDict.object(forKey: "device_id") as! String
                    record.raw          = userDict

                    self.arrRecords.append(record)
                }

                self.sortRecords()
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: I think you can use `.childChanged` event type to detect whenever a child at the specified reference is updated or changed

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update specific index path use

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: your_indexpath_array, with: your_Animation)
```

for insert new rows in the table use

```
 tableView.beginUpdates()
 tableView.insertRows(at: your_indexpath_array, with: your_Animation)
 tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I asked.. Please read the question, I know how to update a UITableView cells

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
rootGenerals.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    //your code
})
```

so every time new child user is added, it will read only new data

Comment: But what if the child updated and not added? what is the best way to sync between one which updated in the server and the same row which belongs to it in the tableview?

Comment: when you just run your app, at first it reads every child that is in your firebase. If new child is added while code is already running, it will read only new child. Then you can just reload the whole table or insert only new row into your table. For updates of a child there is similar method special for changed child. Hope I answered all the questions, here you can find all the methods from official documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data